# git ,how to go back?

Tags: git, heroku, github

I did these operation:

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "Finished layout and routes"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge filling-in-layout
$ git push 
$ git push heroku
```

But then I found the program messed up. I want to go back to last commit. Both local and github and heroku. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In all of your branch, type

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

this will reset and discard all the changes to the last commit.

if you don't want to discard your changes in wrong commit, you can use

```
git reset --mixed HEAD^
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both `master` and `filling-in-layout` are the branches you touched:

```
# Reset master to its previous commit
git checkout master
git reset --hard master@{1}

# Reset filling-in-layout to its previous commit
git checkout filling-in-layout
git reset --hard filling-in-layout@{1}

# Push to GitHub, forcing the loss of history
git push --force

# Same, for the heroku remote
git push --force heroku
```